# Replace cell values, match list elements and switch the pair

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of duplicates `l1 <- list(c("a","b"), c("1","2"),c("x","y"))`. There is also a dataframe as such:

```
     df <- structure(list(names = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"a", "x", "y"), class = "factor"), values = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

> ```
>   names values
> 1     a      0
> 2     1      0
> 3     x      0
> 4     y      0
> ```

I would like to replace any occurrences of these names with its pair from the l1 list. The desired output with df would be:

> ```
>   names values
> 1     b      0
> 2     2      0
> 3     y      0
> 4     x      0
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An idea to do this in a vectorized manner is to `unlist` our list (given that we always have pairs), and `match` it with the df column. We then handle the index returned by `match` as follows:

If it is an odd number, leave it as is. If it is even, then subtract 2 because it is referring to the second element of the pair. Then we add 1 to get the other element's index. We finally use these indices to filter our list, i.e.

```
i1 <- unlist(l1)
i2 <- match(df2$names, i1)
i1[replace(i2, i2 %% 2 == 0, (i2 - 2)[i2 %% 2 == 0]) + 1]
#another slick way of writing the above can be i1[i2 + c(-1,1)[(i2 %% 2) + 1L]]
#courtesy of @Jaap

#[1] "b" "2" "y" "x"
```

Comment: an alternative for the last line: `i1[i2 + c(-1,1)[(i2 %% 2) + 1L]]`

Answer (score 4):

Using *chartr*:

```
chartr("ab12xy", "ba21yx", df$names)
# [1] "b" "2" "y" "x"
```

**Note:** This only works when we have single characters like `c("a", "b")`, would fail if we had `c("apple", "pear")`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can convert the `l1` into a dataframe, `group_by` `name`, reverse the `value` (to match with the pair) and then do a `left_join` with `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  left_join(enframe(l1) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(value1 = rev(value)), by = c('names' = 'value')) %>%
  select(value1, values)

#  value1 values
#1      b      0
#2      2      0
#3      y      0
#4      x      0
```